# Using storage_path from another Laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, storage

I have an application that uses two different Laravel apps talking to the same database. App 1 is called BUILDER and App 2 is called VIEWER. In production I use S3 for storing files submitted within the application. For local development I use the *storage/app/public* folder in BUILDER.

The local dev setup is that BUILDER runs on localhost:8000 and VIEWER on locahost:8001

Now here comes my problem. In production both apps use the same S3 bucket for storage. So somehow I need to set this up similarly for local development.

The BUILDER is working fine, uploading and reading its files from the *storage/app/public* folder with FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public in .env

The VIEWER is also reading these files fine, creating correct URL's after I added a new disk in the config (BUILDER_URL is set in .env to localhost:8000 which is the URL for the BUILDER)

```
'builder_public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('BUILDER_URL') . '/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

BUT... I need to somehow be able to also upload files from the VIEWER app that should end up in the same storage folder as the BUILDER.

So in my VIEWER app I would like my builder_public disk to be something like this:

```
'builder_public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => builder_storage_path('app/public'), // here 
            'url' => env('BUILDER_URL') . '/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Is there some way I can share the storage/app folder between two separate Laravel apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. if you are using Linux server, try below command

```
ln -s SOURCE_FOLDER DESTINATION_FOLDER
```

it will create folder short cut but still, your both application will use the same location(DESTINATION_PATH)

If you are using different servers, try `mount` command.

Comment: Thank you. That's a good solution. I would however prefer to find a way to do this via just the configuration of the apps. As many developers are working on this on many different platforms.

Comment: I ended up adding another environment variable where the developer can add the local path to the storage folder. This variable is then used in the filesystems array. But I'll mark this as the correct answer anyway, since it's a really good one for other cases.